# How to run gulp task in visual studio code?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I have opened my work-space in Visual Studio Code and I have setup gulp tasks. Now I am running gulp tasks in CMD windows. Have do I run gulp tasks directly from VS Code?

Say I have gulp tasks for

1. Test
2. Serve
3. Build

Comment: How exactly do you run the tasks from CMD? I can't get it to work - neither in VS Code nor in PowerShell... What do you type **precisely** to execute a task? I have gulp installed both locally and globally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally VS code auto detect gulp task.

As you can see in [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) doc

> Pressing **F1** and then typing **Run Task** followed by Enter will list all
>   available tasks. Selecting one and pressing Enter will execute the
>   task.

hope this helps

Comment: I'm doing what you mentioned but in my version (1.7.1) there's no Gulp tasks being listed at all. The *gulpfile.js* looks [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616268/cant-execute-the-task-in-vs-code-to-run-gulpfile-js?noredirect=1#comment68477710_40616268) and is placed in the root, as just as described in the question.  I have gulp installed both locally and globally. What can I be doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot it? I.e. how do I verify that I can run the tasks from PowerShell directly? Etc...

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I have gulp installed via npm, deleted the tasks.json file, and when I press F1 to run task, VSCode does not detect Gulp.  Has anyone ran into this issue?

Comment: It seems "it should just show up" is the extent of the support we're going to get