# Can't execute the task in VS Code to run gulpfile.js

Tags: powershell, npm, gulp, task, visual-studio-code

Trying to follow roughly [this guide](https://cmatskas.com/setting-up-a-gulp-task-with-visual-studio-code/) (as many like this one). In *tasks.json* I've added the following, right next to *build* task.

> {
>     "taskName": "gulpify",
>     "args": [],
>     "showOutput": "always",
>     "isBuildCommand": true
>   }

In *gulpfile.js* I've added the following.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
//gulp.task("default", "gulpify");
gulp.task("gulpify", function () {
  alert("bzz");
  console.log("bzz");
});
```

When I execute the task from the embedded workbench command line (not PowerShell but the internal that opens inside VS Code), I get the error saying the below. I've tried both with and without comment on the "default" line in the sample above (because I'm not clear on what it does but many blogs have it, hehe).

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-gulpify"

When I google it, I get that I need to have Gulp installed both locally and globally (which I have). It's also suggested that I need to be on the same level as *project.json* (which I believe I am since I clicked on that file and have it open). I can run the *build* task, too, so I'm guessing I've missed something rather easy but confusing to an ignorant person.

How to troubleshoot it?

Comment: The blog post you have referenced seems to be outdated. Gulp tasks are available via vscode command palette by default if you create a gulpfile.js you can just hit `F1 -> run task` and will find your gulp task listed in the selection list. A tasks.json config entry is not required.

Comment: It seems not to work on my system. I have Code 1.7.1 and the file *gulpfile.js* is placed at the same location as *project.json*. When I hit F1, I only see the *build* that's declared in *tasks.json*. Am I missing an extension? WHat else can I do about it?

Comment: Honestly, I quite using Gulp so long ago. Its just not useful anymore. All the tech you use already has built in task systems. NPM, VS Code. I should of mentioned first, I attempted to download gulp to get the task you had working. Because the current project I am working in is a TypeScript ESNext w/ a ES2021-Target and an ESM module w/ Node 18.03 as its engine, gulp broke my dependencies, and I couldn't get it to work without installing older versions of dependencies that other dependencies for my project uses.

Comment: I tried switching to the older versions, and stuff in my project started breaking. If you want to develop for 2013 use Gulp. to develop a project that works in 2030, what ever you do, don't use gulp, thats my opinion anyways. It looks like Grunt, Gulp, Jake, etc.... are all pretty dead projects at this point. One of there websites said there not working on it because "it is a finished piece of software" which made me literally LOL. Software is never finished, all software has to be maintained to stay robust & secure for users to use. Just FYI: **VSCode & NPM offer everything I need task wise**