# Autodetect of gulpfile.json in VS Code doesn't work

Tags: gulp, task, visual-studio-code

I'm following [this blog](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_autodetecting-gulp-grunt-and-jake-tasks) and despite following it as closely as possible, I can't get the tasks defined in the *gulpfile.json* file to show when I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and choose *run task*. The other task, *build*, shows, though. The file for gulp is placed at the same level as *project.json*, i.e. at the root of the project.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the *autodetecting* process?

Comment: can you run these tasks via command line? if you can, can you post your gulpfile? Can you reproduce the issue with this project: https://github.com/skolmer/i18n-tag-examples/tree/master/Simple

Comment: @Steffen I've deleted the project and closed it again, reinstalled Node, NPM and Gulp and now I can run tasks from PowerShell. However, still no listing in the foldout when I hit F1 in VS Code. It's not such a huge issue **but** it will be a problem when deploying in the production environment later on, as the task isn't automated at the moment (optimally, I'd like it to run when *dotnet restore* or *dotnet build* is carried out).

Comment: Can you post more details about your configuration? your tasks.json and gulpfile.json vor example?

Comment: @Steffen Tasks.json I've tried with was the default dotnet build but also entirely empty and also as shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616268/cant-execute-the-task-in-vs-code-to-run-gulpfile-js), which also shows the contents of the gulpfile.json. I can now run it from the console but it's still not found by VS Code...